# Expression.Or - variable 'a' of type 'Appointment' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees, func

I try to concate two expressions but get error mention in title on Compile method:

```
 Expression<Func<Appointment, bool>> week1 = StartDateIsBetween(lastMonday, nextSunday);
 Expression<Func<Appointment, bool>> week2 = EndDateIsBetween(lastMonday, nextSunday);
 BinaryExpression weekOr = Expression.Or(week1.Body, week2.Body);

 Func<Appointment, bool> week = Expression.Lambda<Func<Appointment, bool>>(weekOr, week1.Parameters.Single()).Compile();
```

Additional two method to create Expressions:

```
 private Expression<Func<Appointment, bool>> StartDateIsBetween(DateTime beginningDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        return a => a.StartDate >= beginningDate && a.StartDate <= endDate;
    }

    private Expression<Func<Appointment, bool>> EndDateIsBetween(DateTime beginningDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        return a => a.EndDate >= beginningDate && a.EndDate <= endDate;
    }
```

Any idea how to fix this error ? I am beginner with expression trees :/

Comment: are you sure you really need an expression tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`week1` and `week2` have different parameters, because they are created separately. The easiest way would be to use `ExpressionInvoke` on your existing expressions, with new `ExpressionParameter` instance:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Appointment));
var weekOr = Expression.Or(Expression.Invoke(week1, param), Expression.Invoke(week2, param));

var week = Expression.Lambda<Func<Appointment, bool>>(weekOr, param).Compile();
```

Comment: Thank You very much! I am confusing with this expressions and how it works :/